# std::map - adding element using subscript operator Vs insert method

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand and make sure if three different ways to insert elements into a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) are effectively the same.

```
std::map<int, char> mymap;
```

Just after declaring `mymap` - will inserting an element with value `a` for key `10` be same by these three methods?

1. `mymap[10]='a';`
2. `mymap.insert(mymap.end(), std::make_pair(10, 'a'));`
3. `mymap.insert(std::make_pair(10, 'a'));`

Especially, does it make any sense using `mymap.end()` when there is no existing element in `std::map`?

Comment: Now. 2 & 3 will do the same thing. No. 1 is different. What happens when there is already an element with a key of 10 in the map?

Comment: Assembly to compare: https://godbolt.org/z/hw23oQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that **(1)** first default-constructs a `key` object in the map in order to be able to return a reference to this object. This enables you to assign something to it.

Keep that in mind if you are working with types that are stored in a map, but have no default constructor. Example:

```
struct A {
   explicit A(int) {};
};

std::map<int, A> m;

m[10] = A(42); // Error! A has no default ctor

m.insert(std::make_pair(10, A(42))); // Ok
m.insert(m.end(), std::make_pair(10, A(42))); // Ok
```

The other notable difference is that (as @PeteBecker pointed out in the comments) **(1)** overwrites existing entries in the map, while **(2)** and **(3)** don't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are effectively the same. Just after declaring `mymap`, all three methods turn `mymap` into `{10, 'a'}`.

It is OK to use `mymap.end()` when there is no existing element in `std::map`. In this case, `begin() == end()`, which is the universal way of denoting an empty container.

Comment: They aren't the same - in the event of there already being an element in the map with that key, **1** will behave differently to **2** and **3**

Comment: @Steve Read the question. Pay special attention to "Just after declaring `mymap`."

Answer (score 1):

(1) is different from (2) and (3) if there exists an element with the same key. (1) will replace the element, where (2) and (3) will fail and return value denoting insertion didn't happen.

(1) also requires that mapped type is default constructible. In fact (1) first default constructs the object if not present already and replaces that with the value specified.

(2) and (3) are also different. To understand the difference we need to understand what the iterator in (2) does. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), the iterator refers to a hint where insertion happens as close to that hint as possible. There is a performance difference depending on the validity of the hint. Quoting from the same page:

> Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just after the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise.(until C++11)
>
> Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just before the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise. (since C++11)

So for large maps we can get a performance boost if we already know the position somehow.

Having said all of these, if the map is just created and you are doing the operation with no prior elements in the map as you said in the question then I would say that all three will be practically same (though there internal operation will be different as specified above).